# How do change the background color of the CurvedNavigationBar selected tab

Tags: flutter, dart, uinavigationbar

I want to change the background color **transparent** that I show in the image.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMlzB.png)

CurvedNavigationBar versions:

```
curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.2
```

Here are the codes I tired:

```
backgroundColor: Color.fromRGB0(255,255,255,0),
backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(0,255,255,255),
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0),
```

None of them worked.  How should i go about.
Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Set inside the scaffold as in the code below,but not working...

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: pageList[_activePage],
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
    animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
    animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
    color: Color(0xff1f5269),
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    onTap: (index) {
      setState(() {
        _activePage = index;
      });
    },
    items: <Widget>[
      Icon(
        Icons.home,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      Icon(
        Icons.tv,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the `color:` parameter, that's what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set color and background color of CurvedNavigationBar

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
    color: Colors.blueGrey,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    items: <Widget>[
      Icon(Icons.add, size: 30),
      Icon(Icons.list, size: 30),
    ],
    onTap: (index) {},
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but i want the background color to be transparent, not white.

Comment: Okay, Then Colors.transparent will work.
If you want to set background color then set it in the scaffold and then Colors.transparent to the background color of CurvedNavigationBar

Comment: Set inside the scaffold as in the code below